# Trying to delete carrierwave folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, ruby-on-rails-4.1

Rails 4.1
Ruby 2
Windows 8.1

CarrierWave does not clean up empty directories. I am trying to get around this by doing the following in my model.

agent.rb:

```
after_destroy :remove_id_directory

def remove_id_directory
  if @agent.avatar
    folder_path = File.join(Cw_storage_folder, 'agent', 'avatar', @agent.id)
    FileUtils.rm_rf(folder_path)
  end
end
```

From agents_controller.rb

```
def destroy
  @agent.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to agent_url }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

When I delete a record, I get the following error message:

```
undefined method `avatar' for nil:NilClass
```

and it points to the first line in the remove_id_directory:

```
if @agent.avatar
```

And the record was not deleted from the DB. If I remove this method and the after_destroy call, then the images are deleted, the record is deleted from the DB, but the folder stays there. Any ideas?

## Possible solutions:

This works:

```
  after_destroy :remove_cw_id_directory

  def remove_cw_id_directory
    FileUtils.rm_rf(File.join(Cw_storage_folder, 'agent', 'agent', self.id.to_s)) if self.avatar
  end
```

Comment: Where you initialized `@agent`? Post that code.

Comment: You mean the controller's destroy method? I posted it now

Comment: Do you have any `before_filter` like `set_agent` method that actually sets the `@agent` like this `@agent = Agent.find(params[:id])`?

Comment: I get to this point from the controller INDEX method. the delete link is: <%= link_to agent, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: 'btn btn-danger' do %> and the agents is the product of @agents.each do |agent|. If the after_destroy is not called, the destroy works fine

Comment: I guess after `destroying the record` there will no `id` of that.So `@agent` will be `nil`.So is the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you don't instantiate any `@agent` variable on your agent model. If you want to get to the record attributes, you need to use `self` instead. 
So change your `remove_id_directory` method to look something like this:

```
def remove_id_directory
    FileUtils.rm_rf(File.join(Cw_storage_folder, 'agent', 'avatar', self.id)) if self.avatar
end
```

Comment: See my edits. This does not work either. Also note that in my case, the id is an integer, so self.id will generate an error and it should be self.id.to_s, still does not work but it does not generate an error

Comment: Ok, can you show me the contents of Images_upload_folder?

Comment: Read my edit. It's an empty folder. As in cw/agent/1, cw/agent/2, etc. when prior to the delete, they used to have image files in them

Comment: Not quite what I asked. Can you post the output of `File.join(Images_upload_folder, 'agent', 'agent')` ?

Comment: I had a syntax error. Your solution works. The same for the other solution I tried. I was using the Image_upload_folder constant, when I should have been using the Cw_images_folder constant